# In what way are value judgments true or false in perspectivism?

Tags: nietzsche

In what way are value judgments true or false in perspectivism?

Be those universal statements like "stealing is wrong" or "I should not steal that".

Comment: This sounds like a question that can be answered by reading encyclopedia entries on perspectivism, not something specific for SE.

Comment: hm well if it's not come up before i don't see the problem @Conifold

Comment: by which i don't understand what you mean @Conifold encyclopedias can be large things